How do I derive the effective rate per period for backward looking overnight interbank borrowing?
The formula for the effective rate per period (of say $n$ days) for backward looking overnight interbank *borrowing has been quoted as follows in my textbook:
$$
\left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{r_i d_i}{360}\right) - 1 \right) \cdot \frac{360}{n} = R
$$
Here:

$r_i$ is the rate of borrowing per annum that applied to $d_i$ days of the borrowing period.
$n$ is the total number of days in the period, which is the summation of $d_i$ (i.e., $∑_{i=1}^{n} d_i $ )

My approach is that this rate formula has been derived by using the concept of the geometric mean and simple interest
Initially, a principal amount $P_0$ gained simple interest and amounted to
$$
P_0 \left(1 + \frac{r_1 d_1}{360}\right)
$$
after $d_1$ days. This amount then gained simple interest and compounded to amount
$$
P_0 \left(1 + \frac{r_1 d_1}{360}\right) \left(1 + \frac{r_2 d_2}{360}\right)
$$
at the end of $d_2$ days, and so on...
The initial principal after compounding in such a fashion grew to the same amount which gained simple interest over a period of $n$ days at an $R$ percent per annum:
$$
P_0 \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{r_i d_i}{360}\right)\right) = P_0 \left(1 + \frac{R n}{360}\right)
$$
I don't understand why the initial principal gained "simple interest" at $r_i$ rate for $d_i$ days and then got compounded again at resp. $r_i$ rate for the rest $d_i$ days, instead of gaining "compound interest" at resp $r_i$ rate for $d_i$ days and then compounding again for the rest of the days, making the previous equation as follows:
$$
P_0 \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{r_i}{360}\right)^{d_i}\right) = P_0 \left(1 + \frac{R}{360}\right)^n
$$
But I am unable to solve for $R$ using the equation above.
Is there a convention in interbank borrowing to use only simple interest since for short periods of borrowing compound interest & simple interest roughly have the same value, and, is my derivation using simple interest and geometric mean correct? Please help.
*Edit: assumption here is that the overall period composed of subperiods 1, 2 etc. lasts less than a year.

Everything you have written up to and including your 2nd to last equation is correct. From "I don't understand" onwards is incorrect. I don't really know how to explain why what you think is wrong becuase I don't really understand what it is you think. Your last equation just doesn't describe economics of interest.

In case it helps, I think there is an unstated assumption here that the overall period composed of subperiods 1, 2 etc. last less than a year, so that simple interest is appropriate. This is a Money Market loan with different rates for different subperiods.

Thanks for your help Attack68 and nbbo2 Finance is a fairly new subject for me. What I understood from your clarifications is that in such Money Market loans due to their short duration compound interest and simple interest are similar in value for practical purposes. @nbbo2 Yes your unstated assumption is correct.

@Attack68 could you briefly elaborate on the "economics of interest" bit? Is there some general notion which I am missing? Will really help me going ahead.

IMO, the formulas describe conversions between interest rate conventions. Quotes / Fixings are provided exactly within a specific convention and can be transformed to a fixing in a different convention.
